# convert a data.table to a vector rowwise

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table such as:

```
example <- data.table(fir =c("A", "B", "C", "A","A", "B", "C"), las=c( "B", "C","B", "C", "B", "C","C"))

A   B
B   C
C   B
A   C
A   B
B   C
C   C
```

Though I guess the problem is the same with a data.frame.

and I would like to get a vector as this:

```
A, B, B, C, C, B, A, C, A, B, B, C, C, C
```

That's, I want to stack every row on the left hand side...

I've tried **unlist(example)** but it extracts the data columnwise instead.

How can I get it?
I've also tried with apply, transposing and other strange things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in a matrix as well as a data.frame/data.table (though different from a matrix), data is stored column wise, you can transpose it first:

```
as.vector(t(example))
# [1] "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "B" "A" "C" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C"
```

---

A benchmark testing including options provided by @Sotos, @Frank and @Wen using a dummy data set:

```
example <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(LETTERS, 10^7, replace = T), ncol = 1000))
dim(example)
#[1] 10000  1000

library(microbenchmark)
psidom <- function() as.vector(t(example))
sotos <- function() c(t(example))
frank <- function() unlist(transpose(example), use.names = FALSE)
wen <- function() unname(unlist(data.frame(t(example))))

# data.table 1.10.4
microbenchmark(psidom(), sotos(), frank(), wen(), times = 10)

#Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
# psidom()  163.5993  178.9236  393.4838  198.6753  632.1086  1352.012    10
#  sotos()  186.8764  188.3734  467.2117  343.1514  618.3121  1221.721    10
#  frank() 3065.0988 3493.3691 5315.4451 4649.4643 5742.2399  9560.642    10
#    wen() 7316.6743 8497.1409 9200.4397 9038.2834 9631.5313 11931.075    10
```

Another test in data.table dev version 1.10.5:

```
# data.table 1.10.5
psidom <- function() as.vector(t(example))
sotos <- function() c(t(example))
frank <- function() unlist(transpose(example), use.names = FALSE)
fast <- function() `attributes<-`(t(example), NULL)

microbenchmark(psidom(), sotos(), frank(), fast(), times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# psidom() 228.1248 246.4666 271.6772 256.9131 287.5072 354.2053    10
#  sotos() 254.3512 280.2504 315.3487 322.5726 344.7125 390.3482    10
#  frank() 290.5476 310.7076 374.6267 349.8021 431.8451 491.9301    10
#   fast() 159.6006 167.6316 209.8363 196.8821 272.4758 281.3146    10
```

Comment: or `c(t(example))`

Comment: or unname(unlist(data.frame(t(df))))

Comment: @Wen Though it works, it's much too wired than it needs to be. It converts a data frame to a matrix then back to a data frame and then to a vector again. I prefer converting only once.

Comment: @Psidom  as OP mentioned he tried unlist, just want to provide it~ Yes , it is way too wired .

Comment: More idiomatic is `unlist(transpose(example), use.names = FALSE)`, I guess. Data.table provides the `transpose` function.

Comment: Personally, I don't think transforming badly-formatted data into an even worse format is something that really needs a benchmark, but fwiw, somehow I see different results: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37671803#37671803

Comment: @Frank Interesting, I am still getting similar result as of above with `data.table` 1.10.4 and `R` 3.3.2; I guess `t` should be faster than `transpose` in this case since it converts to a matrix/vector directly instead of transpose to another data.table which is what `transpose` good at then unlist it?

Comment: Hm, I am on 3.3.3 and 1.10.5. Yeah, your argument for why `t` should be faster makes sense to me. My benchmark still shows transpose being slower, just not by as much, for some reason.

Comment: @Frank I confirmed your result in data.table 1.10.5. The timings are pretty close. The `fast` option is decent.

Comment: I think the best one is unlist(t(example), use.names = FALSE)  because it's almost as fast as the fastest one but it has an advantage, it works well if the column contains factors.